# Is it advisable to remove Avahi and CUPS-browse?

Tags: debian, cups, avahi

From time to time, Avahi takes 100% CPU and CUPS-browse delays the system shutdown with the message "*a stop job is running for make remote cups printers available locally*".

I know Avahi finds printers, as Xfce shows me 16 printers. I also know I don't need 16 printers. On the other hand, I'm not sure what `cups-browsed` is doing.

I do use a network printer. But I know its IP and model. With that in mind, can I just replace Avahi and CUPS-browse with something more simple instead of fixing them?

Comment: cups can be configured without avahi ; it depends on your infra-structure setup. However, cups tends to eat memory and should be restarted once in a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your use case, you don’t need either package, and you don’t need to replace them with anything — CUPS on its own will be able to provide access to your network printer.

`cups-browsed` is the CUPS component which finds printers on your network, by interpreting Bonjour broadcasts. Since you don’t need to automatically find printers, it’s safe to remove it; you can add the printer you need manually using whichever CUPS printer configuration tool you want. Nothing in Debian strictly depends on `cups-browsed` so you can easily remove it. (As a side note, `cups-browsed` is the component which provides access to driver-less printers, if you enable `CreateIPPPrinterQueues` in `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf`; it will then automatically create printer queues for IPP printers on the network. It turns out printing can be simple, in some cases.)

`avahi-daemon` is a Bonjour server; it broadcasts your computer’s information on the network, and allows other applications to publish and resolve Bonjour information. Since you’re using Xfce you should be able to remove it too, if you don’t need its services. (GNOME on Debian depends on `avahi-daemon` but Xfce doesn’t.) The Bonjour client for most applications is provided by `libavahi-client3`, and you won’t be able to easily remove that because many packages depend on it, including CUPS.